# Full non-interactive start + connect to VM from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, virtual-machines, hyper-v, command-line-interface

I know how to connect to Hyper-V VMs from CLI:

```
vmconnect localhost 'machine'
```

I also know how to start them non-interactively, I do this via shortcut like this:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-VM -Name 'machine'}"
```

But how can we combine two this actions together in a shortcut? I don't want to open Hyper-V console at all. I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-VM -Name 'machine' & vmconnect localhost 'machine'}"
```

It throws:

```
At line:1 char:36
+ & {Start-VM -Name 'machine' & vmconnect localhost 'machine ...
+                                    ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double
quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed
```

Additionally, as it seems to me, one should wait some time interval between starting and connecting, 'cause immediate sequence of such commands won't be executed successfully.

Comment: To concatenate powershell commands on one line use `;` But I'd also insert a delay, the VM won't be up immediately. `powershell.exe -Exec Bypass -C "& {Start-VM -Name 'machine';Sleep 120;vmconnect localhost 'machine'}"` Set the seconds to sleep to a suitable value.

Comment: Doesn't work. Connect is not fulfilled even after 600 time interval, PS window seems to close immediately.

Comment: Maybe vmconnect only works interactively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you are missing: you must import the Hyper-V module before starting the VM and `&` is a invocation operator not a command separator.

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "ipmo hyper-v; Start-VM machine; vmconnect localhost machine"
```

I've tested the above working on Windows 10 1703.

Comment: Spectacular answer.